# How to know when search bar text changes

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uisearchbar

I have a search bar and I need to get a notification when the bar text changes, how can I do that? I need to reload the table view every time the string value of the search bar changes

Comment: Read the docs for `UISearchBar` and its delegate.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Follow the below steps to get it done

Add Delegate methods for your View Controller

```
ViewController: UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate
```

Create IBOutlet for your searchBar

```
@IBOutlet weak var searchBarVar: UISearchBar!
```

Assign Delegates as self to searchBar in viewDidLoad.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    searchBarVar.delegate = self
}
```

Implement the textDidChange delegate method

**Swift 4:**

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    print("searchText",searchText)
}
```

**ObjC**

`- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText;`

Comment: For Swift 4 use: func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, 
          textDidChange searchText: String)